# How can I add location elements programmatically to the web config?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, web-config, forms-authentication

I have an application which creates page routes from a database. My whole site is secured with forms authentication but I need to allow unauthenticated uses to access these routes. I don't want to hard-code `<location>` tags for the routes in the web.config as this will negate me using a database to generate the routes.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you want to store them into the web.config if you're loading them from a database?

Comment: Hi Inuyasha, I don't want to store them, I want to allow user access. My whole site is secured with forms authentication but the routes I create need to be accessed by unauthenticated users.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't start all these urls/routes with a specific path, and then set the location tag for that path? For example, have them all start with /public/, and then use a location tag in web.config to give unauthenticated access to the public path.

Comment: Hi Patmortech. That was going to be my fallback plan. What I'm trying to achieve is a really simple URL as it's intended to be typed in by users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I've found [an answer here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2009/01/21/managing-forms-authentication-access-rules-programmatically.aspx)

Basically it involves creating a folder for each route and putting a web.config file in it allowing access. This approach needs to be coupled with setting RouteExistingFiles to false so that the routes don't get confused with the folders.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using strongly typed configuration classes, why not make the modifications directly in XML?

Here's an abbreviated snippet to demonstrate the concept from some code of mine that performance IIS tuning in the machine.config. The principal is the same for other XML config files though. You just need to create the appropriate XPath statements to do what you need.

```
XmlDocument machineConfigFile = new XmlDocument();
machineConfigFile.Load(MachineConfigPathString);

XmlNode autoConfig = machineConfigFile.SelectSingleNode(@"/configuration/system.web/processModel/@autoConfig");
autoConfig.Value = "false";

machineConfigFile.Save(MachineConfigPathString);
```

When saved, the XmlDocument object will preserve all other untouched document nodes. Very handy. It works great for modifying the machine.config. The only possible issue I can see is that your application will probably reset when you save your changes to the web.config. So test it out in a safe environment with a backup of your web.config just in case the reset causes any undesired outcomes!

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I've given that a go but I've found it crashes VS10 from time to time and also, when it re-writes the web.config it escapes certain characters and this causes problems down the line.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c2kcht0.aspx) for you. I didn't find whether you can modify the config of running server instance this way though.

Comment: Thanks, Zruty. I'd looked at that but although it allows me to change the web.config, it doesn't seem to allow me to alter the location elements. They appear to be in a collection (ConfigurationLocationCollection) which has no .Add method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered implimenting your site security in a different way? Having a portion of the site that allows unauthenticated access and a portion that does not. I am "assuming" (bad) that you are using MVC since you are describing routes - this is very easy to do with both MVC and traditional web form applications.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I'm not using MVC but I am using .NET 4.0. When you say "a portion of the site" I'm not sure how that relates to routes. In this instance, all the routes I'm creating point to the same page. The page accepts unauthenticated users, but the routes don't. As I understand it, I need to allow unauthenticated users to the page and the routes for it to work. Is there another way?

Comment: Not that I know of using the approach that you are taking.